# Merging dataframe output with one index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have output from python terminal with the three rows with the same index number of 0. The three rows that are from a list of dicts, I am wondering how to merge this in to having a sequential index numbers.

```
with open('data file\poi.data', 'r') as f3:    
    data = f3.read()
    data = str(data).split('\n')
    data = list(data)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        datum = data[i]
        datum = ast.literal_eval(datum)
        df = json_normalize(datum)
        pprint(df)
```

The output looks like this

```
       city    lat         lon              name   state
0  Portland  45.52 -122.681944  City of Portland  Oregon
     city        lat         lon             name       state
0  Seatle  47.609722 -122.333056  City of Seattle  Washington
            city        lat         lon                   name       state
0  San Francisco  37.783333 -122.416667  City of San Francisco  California
```

I would like the output merged, like so:

```
       city    lat         lon              name   state
0  Portland  45.52 -122.681944  City of Portland  Oregon
1  Seatle  47.609722 -122.333056  City of Seattle  Washington
2  San Francisco  37.783333 -122.416667  City of San Francisco  California
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this might be a JSON lines file, so you can try

```
df = pd.read_json(filepath, lines=True)
```

If this doesn't work, fall back to parsing the file by line using `literal_eval`. You can try calling `json_normalize` on the whole list, rather than one at a time.

```
df = json_normalize([literal_eval(d) for d in data])
```

If, for some reason that doesn't work, try what you were doing, but call `concat` on the normalized data.

```
df = pd.concat([json_normalize(literal_eval(d)) for d in data])
```

Comment: I used the second one. @coldspeed

Comment: @tbc Can I suggest one more thing? How does `df = pd.read_json('data file\poi.data', lines=True)` work?